# Specific Tick Styling depending from actual time

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i have 3 axis in my graph. one x-axis containing integer values and two y-axis (left and right) with time values (each hour is one tick, my time format: d3.time.format("%H:%M");).
now i want to draw a red horizontal line at a specific time (Date.now(), so the actual time that is "now"). this line will be updated in a certain interval, so it will "move" when time passes.

How do I customize a certain tick of my time-axis so it will show my red "now"-line?

Comment: Do you want to modify an axis tick for this or draw a separate line?

Comment: i really don't care, i thought the best way would be to modify a tick.

Comment: I think it would be easier to just add a new line at that position. It'll be the same as adding another line or point or bar.

Comment: thanks, i will try that. i am sorry, i am a js and d3 noob, but could you explain how i get the correct y-values?

Comment: You create a new `Date` object and pass that to your scale.

Comment: you cannot imagine how thankful i am right now ;)...it worked!